# Uploading base64 image from Angular to server

Tags: javascript, angular, base64

I'm trying to upload a base64 image from Angular to ExpressJS. I'm using html2canvas to create the base64 image. If I try and upload `imageData` in it's current form I get
`imageData.replace is not a function`. If I try stringifying it like this in angular service

```
const image = JSON.stringify(imageData);
const data = image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');
```

then I get `Buffer is not a constructor`
How can I get it to upload to ExpressJS server successfully? I appreciate any help!

component

```
       
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        sleep(5000).then(() => {
            const table = document.getElementById('table');
            this.dataUrl = html2canvas(table).then(function (canvas) {
                const res = canvas.toDataURL();
                return res;
            });
            this.angularService.uploadImage('png', this.dataUrl);
        });
    }
```

service

```
    uploadImage(contentType, imageData) {
        console.log("imageData", imageData)
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        if (contentType === 'jpeg') {
            headers.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg;');
        } else if (contentType === 'png') {
            headers.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg;');
        }

        const data = imageData.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');
        const buff = new Buffer(imageData, 'base64');
        return this.http.put(
            environment.slsLocal + '/update-image-url',
            buff.buffer,
            { headers: headers }
        );
    }
```

console.log('imageData', imageData) in service looks like this
[image]

Comment: You do set content-type to `'image/jpeg'` in both cases, but I don't think, that is the problem. You call the `uploadImage` function outside the `then()` of the `sleep()`. So, it looks to me like `uploadImage` is getting called before `this.dataUrl` is set.

Comment: I removed the subscribe because it doesn't let a subscribe inside a promise chain. It recognizes function now. Same errors mentioned before ```Buffer is not a constructor``` and ```imageData.replace is not a function``` are still happening so nothings changed. See updated image and updated console.log in service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues.

1. `html2canvas(table).then` returns promise. Not `res`. You have to call `this.angularService` inside `html2canvas(table).then`.
2. I am not sure what you are trying to do with `const buff = new Buffer(imageData, 'base64');`. If you want to upload the base64 contents, just put `data`.

Also please note that you have to `subscribe` the return of `this.http.put` because HTTP request will not thrown to your server unless it is subscribed.

Put it together.

**component**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    sleep(5000).then(() => {
        const table = document.getElementById('table');
        html2canvas(table).then(function (canvas) {
            const res = canvas.toDataURL();
            this.dataUrl = res;
            this.angularService.uploadImage('png', this.dataUrl)
                .subscribe( result => {
                  // your logic
                } );
        });
    });
}
```

**service**

```
uploadImage(contentType, imageData) {
    console.log("imageData", imageData)
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (contentType === 'jpeg') {
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg;');
    } else if (contentType === 'png') {
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg;');
    }

    const data = imageData.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');
    return this.http.put(
        environment.slsLocal + '/update-image-url',
        data,
        { headers: headers }
    );
}
```

Comment: When I move this.angularService.uploadImage inside .then() I get ```ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.angularService.uploadImage is not a function```. It doesn't recognize it inside then(). It recognizes it because I see the dataUrl being passed to service so I'm not sure that's the issue

Comment: Same errors mentioned before ```Buffer is not a constructor``` and ```imageData.replace is not a function``` are still happening in same scenarios in post so nothings changed. See updated image and updated console.log in service